# Using the result of a statement in another

Tags: sql

I've got the follow 2 SQL statements

```
select 
    Fleet, SUM(hours) as Operating 
from 
    table
where 
    colE = 'Operating' 
    and START_TIME >= '2012-01-01' and END_TIME<='2013-01-01' 
    and FLEET IS NOT NULL
group by 
    fleet 
order by 
    FLEET asc


select Fleet, SUM(hours) as Delay
from table
    where colE='Delay'  and START_TIME>='2012-01-01' and END_TIME<='2013-01-01' and FLEET IS NOT NULL
        group by fleet order by FLEET asc
```

I need the result of both these statments to basically show

```
       select Fleet, (Operating / Delay ) as Calculated Col from table
```

Could anyone help me lead me in the direction of how to do this? New to sql so I believe I should use temp tables?

Thanks!

Comment: Now that I'm looking again, I'm starting to think that CASE statements will do this even easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way is to join the two results:

```
select a.Fleet, (Operating / Delay ) as Calculated_Col
from (select Fleet, SUM(hours) as Operating 
      from table
      where colE = 'Operating' 
      and START_TIME >= '2012-01-01'
      and END_TIME<='2013-01-01' 
      and FLEET IS NOT NULL
      group by fleet) a
join (select Fleet, SUM(hours) as Delay
      from table
      where colE='Delay'
      and START_TIME>='2012-01-01'
      and END_TIME<='2013-01-01'
      and FLEET IS NOT NULL
      group by fleet) b 
      on a.fleet = b.fleet
order by a.FLEET asc
```

Comment: Thanks Bohemian, if I wanted to add a third result into the mix would I just add another join? eg select a.Fleet, (Operating / (Delay1 + Delay2) ) as Calculated_Col

Comment: Worked Perfect thank you! I added extra 5 statments by adding more joins and kept the on logic to the first operating fleet.

Comment: Sam, glad this works but take a look at using case statements rather than multiple joins.  On large tables you may see a difference in performance.

Answer (score 2):

Simple `INNER JOIN` should do:

```
SELECT op.Fleet, (Operating / Delay) AS Calc FROM
(select 
    Fleet, SUM(hours) as Operating 
    from table
    where 
        colE = 'Operating' 
        and START_TIME >= '2012-01-01' and END_TIME<='2013-01-01' 
        and FLEET IS NOT NULL
    group by fleet 
) AS op INNER JOIN (
select Fleet, SUM(hours) as Delay
    from table
    where colE='Delay'  and START_TIME>='2012-01-01'
        and END_TIME<='2013-01-01' and FLEET IS NOT NULL
    group by fleet
) AS de ON op.Fleet = de.Fleet
ORDER BY op.Fleet ASC
```

Comment: how does this perform the requested calculation?

Comment: @Bohemian: Just re-read the question and I misunderstood it. I didn't see the divide by part. I have updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks Guys, it works great for 2 the results, just so for my knowledge if I wanted to add an extra variable statment into the mix, would I simply add another inner join?

Comment: I think a join is less efficient than you need.  You could also do this with case statements.  Others will know better but I think it might be less work on the db.

Answer (score 1):

This is more general but may be helpful in similar situations.

You can select values into declared variables like this.

```
Declare @X as Decimal, @Y as Decimal
Set @X = (Select [field] from [table] where [conditions])
Set @Y = (Select [field] from [table] where [conditions])

select @X / @Y
```

More specifically, you coud do your query with case statments.

```
SELECT
    Fleet
    ,SUM(CASE WHEN @colE = 'Operating' THEN hours END) 
    / SUM(CASE WHEN @colE = 'Delay' THEN hours END) as Calculated
FROM table
WHERE [conditions]
```

Answer (score 0):

If your SQL engine supports CTE's (Common Table Expressions; e.g. SQL SErver does, others will, too), you can use something like this:

```
;WITH BaseDataOperating AS 
(
select 
    Fleet, SUM(hours) as Operating 
from 
    table
where 
    colE = 'Operating' 
    and START_TIME >= '2012-01-01' and END_TIME<='2013-01-01' 
    and FLEET IS NOT NULL
group by 
    fleet 
), BaseDataDelay AS 
(
   select 
       Fleet, SUM(hours) as Delay
   from 
       table
   where 
       colE = 'Delay'
       and START_TIME >= '2012-01-01' and END_TIME <= '2013-01-01' 
       and FLEET IS NOT NULL
   group by 
       fleet 
)
SELECT 
   bdo.Fleet, 
   (bdo.Operating / bdd.Delay ) as Calculated_Col 
FROM
   BaseDataOperating bdo
INNER JOIN
   BaseDataDelay bdd ON bdo.Fleet = bdd.Fleet
```

Basically create one CTE for the "operating" numbers, one for the "delay" numbers, and then select from an inner join across those two CTE's